# Use of variable in bash script making use of awk

Tags: awk

I would like to create a script to dynamically call this awk command:

```
awk '/2019.07.16 09:00/, /2019.07.16 10:00:/' mylog.log | awk '$3 == "-" && $4 != "-" {print $4}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

I'm usually invoking that command successfully but now I want to execute it multiple times changing time ranges, I'm having difficulties in setting times, here follows what I tried:

```
for counter in {7..7}
    do
        echo "Counter "$counter
        echo /2019.07.16 0"$counter":00/, /2019.07.16 0"$((counter+1))":00:/

        # The commented code shows unsuccessful attempts
        #awk '/2019.07.16 0"$counter":00/, /2019.07.16 "$((counter+1))":00:/' mylog.log | awk '$3 == "-" && $4 != "-" {print $4}' | sort | uniq | wc -l

        # The commented code shows unsuccessful attempts
        #startvar=0"$counter":00/,
        #echo $startvar
        #awk -v start="$startvar" '/2019.07.16 start /2019.07.16 08:00:/' mylog.log | wc -l                 
    done
```

Have you some hint? Thanks in advance, bye

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but have you tried removing the `#`. If this is not the solution, then you need to edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Are you really serious? "have you tried removing the #" :D ?

Comment: If this is not the solution, then you need to edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Gamby I suggest to add a comment `# The commented code shows unsuccessful attempts` above the commented code lines. This will make the question more clear even if it's not needed for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use double quotes instead of single quotes, variable substitution will work between the quotes. With this approach you have to quote all `$` and `"` characters in the `awk` script as `\$` or `\"`.

```
awk "/2019.07.16 0$counter:00/, /2019.07.16 0$((counter+1)):00:/" mylog.log | ...
```

Note that the solution with `0$counter:00` and `0$((counter+1)):00` works only if `counter+1 < 10`.

If you also want to filter two-digit hour values, you could use printf formatting for the hour string:

```
start=$(printf "%2.2d" "$counter")
stop=$(printf "%2.2d" "$((counter+1))")

awk "/2019.07.16 $start:00:/, /2019.07.16 $stop:00:/" mylog.log | ...
```

If your actual input data contains the date and time in every line, and if you don't need the minute 00 of the next hour, you could simplify the pattern:

```
awk "/2019.07.16 $start:/" mylog.log | ...
```

For example with `start=07` this should print all lines from `07:00:00` to `07:59:59`.

With this simplification you could also combine the two `awk` scripts into one.

```
awk "/2019.07.16 $start:/ && \$3 == \"-\" && \$4 != \"-\" {print \$4}" mylog.log | sort -u | wc -l
```

Note: `sort -u` gives the same output as `sort | uniq`.

For a better solution I would need to know the exact format of the input data.

Assuming the date is in column 1 and the time is in column 2, you could pass the data to `awk` as variables without shell variable expansion in the `awk` script code. This solution allows using single quotes and avoids code injection vulnerability and quoting of `$` or `"` in the script.

```
timepattern=$(printf "^%2.2d:" "$counter")
date="2019.07.16"

awk -v date="$date" -v timepattern="$timepattern" '$1 == date && $2 ~ timepattern && $3 == "-" && $4 != "-" {print $4}' mylog.log | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: It's better to give `awk` the values of the variables with its `-v` option though, as injecting them straight into the `awk` code itself is generally a bad habit (code injection vulnerability).  It also makes for unreadable code, and your last command has a single quote in it that probably shouldn't be there (as well as an unescaped `$`).

Comment: Really thanks :)